# BASH read file for only N rows, sleep for N time and continue where left off

Tags: bash, loops

I have this script below --

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/cygdrive/c/apps/dcm4che-2.0.25-bin/SUID_TEST
BASEDIR=/cygdrive/c/apps/dcm4che-2.0.25-bin/bin
TWIDDLE=/cygdrive/c/apps/dcm4chee-2.17.2-mssql/bin/twiddle.sh
#Administrator login and password
LOGIN=mylogin
PASSWORD=mypass
count=0
exec 3<&0 # Save stdin to file descriptor 3.
exec 0<$INPUT # Redirect standard input.
while read line
do
input1=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1}')
echo "Deleting :" ${input1}
$TWIDDLE -u ${LOGIN} -p ${PASSWORD} -s jnp://192.168.50.51:1099 invoke "dcm4chee.archive:service=ContentEditService" purgeStudy ${input1}
count=$( expr $count + 1 )
sleep 30
done
exec 0<&3 # Restore old stdin.
echo "Counter:" $count # Show deleted items
```

the input file 'SUID_TEST' will have over 100,000 lines in it, with each line looking like '1.2.124.113532.192.168.50.52.20070330.204624.1634650'.

What I am trying to do is have the script read only 50 lines, sleep for 10min and continue reading another 50 lines, sleep for 10min, until it reaches the end of the input file.

Right now, it just runs until it gets to the end of the file.

Could someone help me out with how I could get this going?

thank you

-- just placing some code here - new script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/cygdrive/c/apps/dcm4che-2.0.25-bin/SUID_TEST
BASEDIR=/cygdrive/c/apps/dcm4che-2.0.25-bin/BIN
TWIDDLE=/cygdrive/c/apps/dcm4chee-2.17.2-mssql/bin/twiddle.sh
LOGIN=mylogin
PASSWORD=mypass
cnt=0
count=0
exec 3<&0 #Save stdin to file descriptor 3.
exec 0<$INPUT #redirect standard input
while read input1 rest  # Let read split the line instead of running awk
do
  echo "Row $count"
  ((cnt++))
  echo "Deleting :" ${input1}
  $TWIDDLE -u ${LOGIN} -p ${PASSWORD} -s jnp://192.168.50.51:1099 invoke "dcm4chee.archive:service=ContentEditService" purgeStudy ${input1}
  ((count++))
  if (( cnt == 50 )); then
      echo "Sleeping for 10 minutes on" | date
      sleep 600
      cnt=0
  fi
done
exec 0<$3
echo "Counter:" $cnt #show deleted items
```

Comment: This is wrong: `echo "Sleeping for 10 minutes on" | date`. date does not do anything with its stdin. Use one of `echo "Sleeping for 10 minutes on $(date)"` or `date "+Sleeping for 10 minutes on %c"`

Comment: thanks for the correction on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just count your loop iterations, sleeping and resetting the counter when it hits 50.

```
cnt=0
count=0
while read input1 rest  # Let read split the line instead of running awk
do
  echo "Row $count"
  ((cnt++))
  echo "Deleting :" ${input1}
  $TWIDDLE -u ${LOGIN} -p ${PASSWORD} -s jnp://192.168.50.51:1099 invoke "dcm4chee.archive:service=ContentEditService" purgeStudy ${input1}
  ((count++))
  if (( cnt == 50 )); then
      date
      sleep 600
      cnt=0
  fi
done
```

To remove the need for the `exec` statements, you can simply have the `read` command read from a different file descriptor (3 is customary), then redirect your input file to the while loop's file descriptor 3.

```
while read -u3 input1 rest; do
    ...
done 3< "$INPUT"
```

Comment: thanks for your help on this!  I appears to work and wait as I had hoped.  A couple of other things, I had a 'counter' in there that would show how many items has been 'delete' & it doesn't count correctly any longer.  Maybe as it reads the lines & as it echos back what line it is on in the input file, could it somehow 'number' each line and increment to display what row it is currently echoing?  Also, at the end of each 50 completed, how would I call the 'date/time' so that when I check back I can tell it has been progressing?

Comment: Any ideas how I could get this to echo a 'count' as I described above?  Am I correctly echoing the count in my edited code above at least?  thanks

Comment: thanks chepner, now should I just get rid of all of the 'exec' lines?  Are they still needed?

Comment: Nothing I changed removes the need for the `exec`s, but I can post a change that will remove the need for them.

Comment: You're echoing the wrong counter.  You want `$count`, not `$cnt`.

Comment: @Sigi of course he is! With variable names like that I'm impressed he didn't transpose the two variables completely...

Comment: This also risks to misspell either variable as `$cunt`.

Comment: I intentionally echoed `$count` under the assumption that the absolute row number, not the row number of the current set, was desired. However, I agree with the comment about the dangers of misspellings (as someone whose first name--CLINT--is similarly dangerous in comic books).

Comment: Excellent - thanks for pointing that out.  If I did echo $cunt, depending how large it was it might come back more than once  ;)